# Best way to do a non-mutating inverse tail in javascript using Underscore/Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, underscore.js

I'm an avid user of lodash/underscore in my node.js projects, and I find myself in a situation where I need to recursively iterate through an array from right to left in a manner similar to the below code (assuming that all calls are synchronous):

```
function makeDir(pathArray) {
  var unsulliedPath = clone(pathArray);
  var lastGuy = pathArray.pop();
  var restOfEm = pathArray;
  if dirExists(unsulliedPath) {
    console.log("Your job is done!");
  } else {
    makeDir(restOfEm);
    makeDir(unsulliedPath);
  }
}
```

Having to clone and mutate the pathArray argument bugs me, however. So I could do this:

```
function makeDir(pathArray) {
  var lastGuy = _.last(pathArray);

  // EITHER I could...
  var restOfEm = _(pathArray).reverse().tail().reverse().value(); 
  // OR I could do...
  var restOfEm = _.first(pathArray, pathArray.length - 1);

  if dirExists(pathArray) {
    console.log("Your job is done!");
  } else {
    makeDir(restOfEm);
    makeDir(pathArray);
  }
}
```

Okay, that takes care of having to clone the argument passed in. That underscore incantation is slightly ugly, though.

Do lodash/underscore contain a simpler and clearer method for getting the inverse of  _.rest(), that is, every element except the last?  If not, is there a preferred idiomatic solution for implementing this method in Javascript for use alongside lodash/underscore-style functional libraries, or is this simply nit-picking?

Thanks in advance, and apologies for any glaring omissions or errors in my question.

Comment: looks like you're trying to `mkdir -p`.  why not just use the `mkdirp` package?

Comment: This is a very good question - I'm building a system wherein folders and files in a filesystem tree correspond with documents in a document DB - e.g. every picture in the /foo/bar/pictures dir has a document in mongo with metadata, as does the /foo/bar/pictures directory itself. I'm attempting to verify that the enclosing directories' documents exist as well as the files/folders themselves. Hope thats a decent explanation of my thinking. :3

Comment: This doesn't do that verification for you -- this will just ensure directories get created.  You might as well use mkdirp and each time you write a file out verify it against a list. At the end of the transaction look to see what isn't verified?

Comment: Roger that, this is just example code, my actual (messy) implementation includes the verification stuff but thats non-essential to the question. I think I see the performance benefit of keeping an index of tree nodes to check against, as well as the decrease in cognitive overhead as well, so thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother with underscore/lodash.

```
var last = pathArray.slice(-1)[0];
var rest = pathArray.slice(0, -1);
```

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will do this all for you very easily...

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.splice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice and if you do not want to modify the original, do Array.slice to copy the original and then Array.splice.

ie:

```
var rest = pathArray.slice(0);
var last = rest.splice(-1, 1)[0];
```

Comment: or you could just use slice like @tkone's solution

Comment: Yeah the problem here is that this mutates the original array.  You'd have to do a `var last = pathArray.slice(0)l var rest = last.splice(-1, 1);` in order to copy and then mutate the copy